# change the key labels in a legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I tryed to change key labels on `ggplot`, but I was unsuccessful. When I indicate labels at `scale_color_manual` line the legend appears duplicated. Where is my mistake?

Consider de example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
year=as.integer(rep(2010:2020,each=2)),
type=rep(c("a","b"),11),
value=c(617,186,546,241,430,217,349,188,286,141,446,166,442,167,424,210,421,182,405,190,432,194))

ggplot(mydata,aes(year,value,group=type))+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(
        axis.text=element_text(size=16),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18),
        legend.position=c(.75,.885),
        legend.key = element_rect(color = "white", fill = NA),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=20)
    )+
    labs(x="year",y="number")+
    geom_point(aes(color=type,shape=type),size=3)+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(mydata$year),max(mydata$year), by = 2))+
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,19))+
    scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

But if I replace legend key "a" and "b" with "group a" and "group b" with

```
scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"),labels=c("group a","group b"))
```

I get duplicated legends and the colored bullets become wrong.

[wrong plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN9Xp.png)

Whats going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without changing the factor levels, provided you add the same labels to both the colour and shape scales:

```r
ggplot(mydata,aes(year,value,group=type))+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(
        axis.text=element_text(size=16),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18),
        legend.position=c(.75,.885),
        legend.key = element_rect(color = "white", fill = NA),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=20)
    )+
    labs(x="year",y="number")+
    geom_point(aes(color=type,shape=type),size=3)+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(mydata$year),max(mydata$year), by = 2))+
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,19), labels = c("group a", "group b")) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"), labels = c("group a", "group b"))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry @H1 I didn't notice that. My answer was on the clipboard by the time I saw yours!

Comment: Thanks H 1 and Allan. Although I've been using R for almost 20 years, this is my first "real plot" in ggplot.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused by changing the color labels but not the shape labels.  So you either need to apply the labels to both shape and color or change the `type` factor labels before plotting.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, labels = c("group a","group b"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year,value))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(
    axis.text=element_text(size=16),
    axis.title=element_text(size=18),
    legend.position=c(.75,.885),
    legend.key = element_rect(color = "white", fill = NA),
    legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.text=element_text(size=20)
  )+
  labs(x="year",y="number")+
  geom_point(aes(color=type,shape=type),size=3)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(mydata$year),max(mydata$year), by = 2))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,19))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]